# MySQL Left Outer Join Validation?

Tags: mysql, sql, validation, left-join

I have a table listing locations and the acceptable fields for each location:

Location                       Acceptable Fields 
----------------------------------------------------------|
Location_A                       Address 
Location_A                       Phone 
Location_A                       Hours 
    Location_B                       Address 
Location_B                      Phone

Now, I have a table listing the values that I want to validate against the first table.

ID     Location       Address                   Phone               Hours 
----------------------------------------------------------------------|
1     Location A     123 Some St.     9999999     8-5 
2     Location B     456 Some St.     9999998      8-4 
 
 Now, Location A passes the Hours validation, however, Location B has Hours listed but according to the validation table, it shouldn't be. This should be NULL. I want my query to return Location B, 8-4. Here my MySQL statement that is obviously not working:

```
SELECT Table2.Location, Table2.Hours 
FROM 
    Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 
ON 
    Table1.Location = Table2.Location

WHERE 
    Table2.Hours is not null
    AND Table1.Acceptable_Fields != 'Hours';
```

Comment: let us know .. what output you need exactly

Comment: are the LOCATION values in table1 and table2 listed as shown in your example, I.e. Location_A vs Location A?

Comment: Hi - 1. that was a typo, both are Location_A, Location_B (in both tables)

Comment: The output I'm trying to get is: Location_B  8-4

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT Table1.Location, Table1.Acceptable_Fields
FROM Table1 RIGHT JOIN
    (
        SELECT Location, 'Address' AS col_name, Address AS col_val
        FROM Table2

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Location, "Phone" AS col_name, Phone AS col_val
        FROM Table2

        UNION ALL

        SELECT Location, "Hours" AS col_name, Hours AS col_val
        FROM Table2
    ) T3 ON Table1.Location = Table3.Location
      AND Table3.col_name = Table1.Acceptable_Fields
WHERE Table3.col_name IS NULL AND TAble3.col_val IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this:

Using LEFT JOIN. You will need to left join your control table three times (once for each of the control parameters (i.e. Acceptable Fields) and check for NULLs, like this:

```
SELECT t2.ID,
       t2.Location,
       CASE WHEN a.Acceptable_Fields IS NOT NULL THEN t2.Address END Address,
       CASE WHEN p.Acceptable_Fields IS NOT NULL THEN t2.Phone END Phone,
       CASE WHEN h.Acceptable_Fields IS NOT NULL THEN t2.Hours END Hours 
FROM
Table2 t2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 a ON
t2.Location = a.Location AND a.Acceptable_Fields = 'Address'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 p ON
t2.Location = p.Location AND p.Acceptable_Fields = 'Phone'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 h ON
t2.Location = h.Location AND h.Acceptable_Fields = 'Hours'
```

Using a sub-queries:

```
SELECT t2.ID,
       t2.Location,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Location = t2.Location AND Acceptable_Fields = 'Address') THEN t2.Address END Address,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Location = t2.Location AND Acceptable_Fields = 'Phone') THEN t2.Phone END Phone,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE Location = t2.Location AND Acceptable_Fields = 'Hours') THEN t2.Hours END Hours 
FROM
Table2 t2
```